# enable submit button when jquery.validate has valiated the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

I have a form that is being validated using jquery.validate. 
I have added in reCAPTCHA 2.0 and this is being validated also. 
However I want the form's submit button to be disabled untill the form is valid and this is where I am stuck.

The button is disabled but is not being enabled after the entries and captcha are all validated.

This is my form code

```
    <div class="contact-Form">
        <form id="form">
            <label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input name="firstname" type="text"  id="firstname" class="inputbox" value="" placeholder="Your name...">
            <br><br>
            <label for="name">Email</label><br>
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" class="inputbox" value="" placeholder="Your email address...">
            <br><br>
            <label for="name">Message</label><br>
            <textarea class="messagebox" rows="10" cols="20" name="message" id="message" value="" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcjETAUAAAAAPC7-qXZW4xI89k1EhUzPWnD5mAP" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>
            <input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha required" name="hiddenRecaptcha" id="hiddenRecaptcha">
            <br><br>
            <button id="submit" disabled="disabled" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form> 
    </div>
```

And my javascript

```
    $().ready(function() {

 $("#form").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
    rules: {
        "firstname": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        "email": {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        "message": {
            required: true
        },
        "hiddenRecaptcha": {
            required: function() {
                if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == '') {
                    return true;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "firstname": {
            required: "<br/> You have not entered a name!",
            minlength: "<br/> Your name must consist of atleast 3 characters",
        },
        "email": {
            required: "<br/> You have not entered an email address!",
            email: "<br/> Please use a valid email address!",
        },
        "message": {
            required: "<br/> You have not entered a message!",
        }
    }
});
    $('#form input').on('keyup blur click', function () { // fires on every keyup & blur
            if ($('#form').valid()) {                   // checks form for validity
                $('button.btn').prop('disabled', false);        // enables button
            } else {
                $('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');   // disables button
            }
    });

});

function recaptchaCallback() {
    $('#hiddenRecaptcha').valid();
};
```

Edit

I have changed this function

```
$('#form input').on('keyup blur click', function () { // fires on every keyup & blur
            if ($('#form').valid()) {                   // checks form for validity
                $('button.btn').prop('disabled', false);        // enables button
            } else {
                $('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');   // disables button
            }
    });
```

To this

```
$('#form input').bind('keyup blur click', function () { 
            if ($(this).validate().checkForm()) {
                $('#submit').removeClass('button_disabled').attr('disabled', false); // enables button
            } else {
                $('#submit').addClass('button_disabled').attr('disabled', true);   // disables button
            }
    });
```

It now enables the button when any input is valid. I want it to only enable the button when all inputs are valid.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong please I have checked other posts which is how I managed to get this working up till this point

Answer (score 2):

You can try by removing the disabled attribute from your input btn

example:

$("button.btn").removeAttr("disabled");

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi I thought that was being done in this code                                                                                     $('#form input').on('keyup blur click', function () { // fires on every keyup & blur
            if ($('#form').valid()) {                   // checks form for validity
                $('button.btn').prop('disabled', false);        // enables button
            } else {
                $('button.btn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');   // disables button
            }
    });

});